# Some way to sort a list of dictionaries by a certain value using Quicksort Algorithm? Python

Tags: python, list, dictionary, quicksort

Good morning, I was trying to perform a Quicksort order on a list that contains several dictionaries, where I wanted to order them according to sale_number (smallest to largest).
However, so far it hasn't worked out for me.

```
sale_record = {"device":device,
                "amount": amount,
                "sale number":sale_number,
                "sale price":sale_price,
                "sale total": total_sale
                }

device_list = [{'device': 'laptop', 'quantity': 4, 'sale number': 20003, 'sale price': 337.0, 'sale total': 1348.0},
{'device': 'desktop ', 'quantity': 4, 'sale number': 20003, 'sale price': 292.5, 'sale total': 1170.0},
{'device': 'printer', 'quantity': 2, 'number sale': 20001, 'sale price': 173.75, 'total sale': 347.5}]

def ordering_Quicksort_num_sales(list_devices):
      left = []
      center = []
      right = []
      if len(list_devices(sale_number)) > 1:
          pivot = sale_number[0]
          for i in sale_number:
              if i < pivot:
                  left.append(i)
              elif i == pivot:
                  center.append(i)
              elif i > pivot:
                  right.append(i)
              #print(left+["-"]+center+["-"]+right)
          return left + center + right
      else:
          return list(list_devices(sale_number))
```

The error it launch is:
if len(list_devices(sale number)) > 1:
TypeError: object 'list' is not callable

How it was claimed sale_number:

```
correlative_number = int(input("Enter the sale registration number: "))
quantity = int(input("Enter the number of devices sold: "))
sale_number = 20000 + correlative_number
sale_record = {"device":device,
                "amount": amount,
                "sale number":sale_number,
                "sale price":sale_price,
                "sale total": total_sale
                }
```

(They asked me to ask for a number for the product and then put it 20000. But also sort it, so I just put a plus 20000)

Comment: 'However, so far it hasn't worked out for me.' -> Please give more details on what hasn't worked out for you.
Also the third element in `device_list` has a typo. Based on the context, `number sale` should be `sale number`. Could this be the problem?

Comment: @Sashi Yeah, It was my mistake at the time to translate the words. I already edit the post.

Comment: The error message tells you what goes wrong.

Comment: `back left + center + right /n the rest:` This also looks like syntax error. Perhaps you want an `else` statement.

`TypeError: object 'list' is not callable`. This means that you cannot call a list as you would do a function. You must access the elements using their index.
`list_devices(sale_number)` is incorrect.
`list_devices[sale_number]` is correct. Here also you must make sure that `sale_number` is an integer `< len(list_devices)`.

Where are you calling the function `ordering_Quicksort_num_sales`? 
It seems the variable `sale_number` is defined outside your function.

Comment: @Sashi This is how I claim the sale_number:
correlative_number = int(input("Enter the sale registration number: "))
quantity = int(input("Enter the number of devices sold: "))
sale_number = 20000 + correlative_number
sale_record = {"device":device,
                "amount": amount,
                "sale number":sale_number,
                "sale price":sale_price,
                "sale total": total_sale
                }
(They asked me to ask for a number for the product and then put it 20000. But also sort it, so I just put a plus 20000)
                }

Comment: In that case you shouldn't be using `sale_number` as a list. In `pivot = sale_number[0]` and in `for i in sale_number:`. See [https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html] for what you can and cannot do with a list.